# Using Mouse Click to select jCombobox Item

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, mouseclick-event

I am using NetBeans GUI palette to design my application in java.

I am also using AutocompleteDecorator on my `JComboBox` and it works well.

I populate my `JComboBox` with data from my database when the program first runs but the problem is I can't use mouse click on my `JComboBox` to populate my `JTable` with my selected item from my `JComboBox`. It doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using an `ActionEvent` but for each letter I typed in, it populated my `JTable` with the same item in consecutive rows.
I also tried using `StateChanged` event but it did pretty much the same as the `ActionEvent`.

What I'm trying to achieve is type in my editable `JComboBox` and it autocompletes for me and the click on an item I want and input the selected item data on my `JTable`.

Please not everything else works except the mouse click part.

Your help would be greatly appreciated. Sample code below:

`addresultOnTable()` populates my `JTable`

```java
public void addDatabaseToComboBox() throws Exception {
    try{
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:C:\\Program Files\\ERS\\Database\\EmployeeDB", "axle","axle");
        String list = "Select * from STOCKSTABLE";
        PreparedStatement pst4;
        ResultSet rs4;
        pst4 = con.prepareStatement(list);
        rs4 = pst4.executeQuery();
        while(rs4.next()){
            int n = 1;
            //String name = rs4.getString(n);
            jComboBoxTest.addItem(rs4.getString(n));
            n++;
        }
        jComboBoxTest.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        System.out.println("Passed!");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainMenu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

---

```java
private void jComboBoxTestMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        addResultOnTable();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestPanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: To do that adMouseListener must be added to JCombobox. Your codes are incomplete.

Comment: Don't use a MouseListener. The JComboBox was designed to be used with an `ActionListener` or `ItemListener`. I typically use an `ActionListener`.

Comment: [How to Use Combo Boxes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)